# GZServer problem >> Could not open file[empty.world]

Tags: gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have **ubuntu 12.04** and installed gazebo by  **Pre-compiled binaries** from [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.5/install#Pre-compiled_binaries)

> i don't any change in bashrc expect:

> **source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh**

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ **gdb --args gzserver empty.world**

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/gzserver...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/gzserver-
1.5.0...done.
done.
```

(gdb) **run**

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/gzserver empty.world
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe5293700 (LWP 4328)]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error [Server.cc:238] Could not open file[empty.world]
[Thread 0x7fffe5293700 (LWP 4328) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 4252) exited with code 0377]
(gdb)
```

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ **echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH**

```
/usr/share/gazebo-1.5:/usr/share/gazebo_models
```

and there is my empty.world:
/usr/share/gazebo-1.5/worlds/empty.world

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1810/gzserver-problem-%3E%3E--could-not-open-file%5Bempty.world%5D/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you have to add the path to the .world file

```
$ gzserver /<path>/share/gazebo-1.5/worlds/empty.world
```

Cheers, Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-14**:
gzserver /usr/share/gazebo-1.5/worlds/empty.world . after run gzclientin another terminal this error showed: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and this window opened: "The application Gazebo has closed unexpectly" and it gave me this title for error "gzserver-1.5.0 crashed with SIGABRT in raise()". help plz

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-14**:
I recreated the steps with gazebo 1.5 and for me it works. Do you get the same error when you run $ gazebo /<path>/share/gazebo-1.5/worlds/empty.world ? Or just simply $ gazebo ? Maybe you are loading something from your world file that gives a segfault.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-15**:
i'm trying to install gazebo again but it gave me this error: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1837/sudo-apt-get-install-gazebo-gazebo-depends-but-it/